# How to avoid "E0463: can't find crate for `test` can't find crate" when building for thumbv7m-none-eabi?

Tags: rust, arm, embedded, rust-language-server

RLS is giving the following error message when working on a project with an ARM target:

> E0463: can't find crate for `test`  can't find crate

Reproduction:

```
cargo new --bin app
cd app
mkdir .cargo
echo '[build]' > .cargo/config
echo 'target = "thumbv7m-none-eabi"' >> .cargo/config
echo '#![no_std]' > src/main.rs
rls --cli
```

I believe this is because there is no test crate for the ARM target.

Is there a way to avoid this error?

There are several other SO posts on E0463 but appears those are configuration errors. The above is purely an RLS question. It's causing my editor to display errors and not do code complete, etc.

Comment: Issues with running RLS in no_std projects is what pushed me to switch over to Rust Analyzer. I also want to note that RLS isn't being actively developed and is poised to be superceded by RA.

Comment: @IvanC I am getting the same error with rust-analyzer.

Comment: I checked and I also have to add ```[unstable]
build-std = ["core"]```
to .cargo/config.

Comment: @IvanC Does this mean you have to use unstable?

Comment: In general you have to use nightly if you want to cross-compile.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting this with rust-analyzer despite using the `build-std = ["core"]` as well as nightly, and in fact despite including the `checkOnSave.allTargets=false` setting.  Sigh.

Comment: Update: it was failing because I wasn't modifying languages.toml properly.  Adding a `.helix/languages.toml` in my project root, with a `[language.config]` section inside `[[language]] name="rust" ` with just that setting fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you include:

```json
{
  "rust-analyzer.cargo.target": "<your target architecture>",
  "rust-analyzer.check.allTargets": false,
}
```

and you are still getting the can't find crate for 'test' error on vscode, see if you have the Cargo extension by panicbit installed (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=panicbit.cargo).  It also uses cargo check on save without regards to the target architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Found this in a [github issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/issues/3801#issuecomment-1485414210):

In the file `.vscode/settings.json`:

```json
{
    "rust-analyzer.check.allTargets": false,
    "rust-analyzer.check.extraArgs": [
        "--target",
        "<your target architecture>"
    ]
}
```

Replace `<your target architecture>` with the right target.

Comment: I'm not sure when this changed but VS Code now seems to expect `check` instead of `checkOnSave`